# How to disable visualstudio.com stored project's multiple check-out?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, vcs-checkout

I have a project stored in visualstudio.com. However when I have a file checked out, my colleagues can do the same. How can I disable that feature? I went to TEAM -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control in VS 2012 and disabled "Enable multiple check-out". However nothing seems to have changed. Do I need to do something else with that? Secondly, I read [this](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs_source_cont_1.html) but when I right click a file and chose "Check-out for edit", it only has "Unchanged" and "CheckIn" lock types but no "Check-out" which, as I understand, is the thing I need to chose. So, is there a way to make sure only one person can edit a file at one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of workspace are you using? Make sure you're using a server workspace. If you're using a local workspace which is the default when you create a new workspace in VS 2012/TFS 2012, checkout locks are disabled. For more info on local and server workspaces:
[Decide Between Using a Local or a Server Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx).

Comment: Being the creator of the project I went and set it to Server workspace. Unfortunately, people can still check out even though I have already checked-out. Did I miss any other settings? Also, the option to chose "check out lock" did not appear :(

Comment: That's because their workspaces are still local. They need to convert their workspaces from local to server. To do that, that can edit their workspaces in Team Explorer, go to Advanced settings, and flip location from local to server.

Comment: Yes! That's what it was. We all had to convert our workspaces, setting the tfs settings was not the full solution. Thanks a lot!